# I feel my elbows locked in a pullup

Tags: pull-ups, elbows

When I reach halfway my chin up I feel my elbows are trapped If I stand go one 1inch higher I can continue it normally

I can hold a dead hang for 1.5 minutes and do a 10 negatives in a row
I don't think my strength is the issue I just feel my elbows are stuck and cannot proceed in bending

Comment: I do an overhand pullup

Comment: It's hard to say if it's a form problem, muscle weakness problem, or a structural (bone) problem. Unfortunately, I don't think it's anything we can assess. I would highly suggest a short session with a trainer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.